# Filter a set of data

Tags: groovy

Having a set of data representing classrooms with the following properties

```
List classrooms = [
    [code: "A", floor: 1, number: 20, airConditioned: true],
    [code: "A", floor: 1, number: 21, airConditioned: false],
    [code: "A", floor: 1, number: 22,, airConditioned: false],
    [code: "A", floor: 2, number: 20, airConditioned: false],
    [code: "B", floor: 1, number: 21, airConditioned: false],
    [code: "B", floor: 2, number: 30, airConditioned: false],
    [code: "C", floor: 1, number: 40, airConditioned: true]
]
```

I need to filter by code, floor and air conditioned each one of them are a list of values that could be empty for example

```
List codes = ["A",  "C"]
List floors = [1]
List airConditioned = [true, false]
```

Right now i am trying the following

```
List filter(List<Integer> floorList, List<String> codeList, List<Boolean> airConditionedList) {
    List classrooms = getClassrooms()
    List classroomList = []

    classrooms.each { c ->
        if (c.floor in floorList && c.code in codeList && c.airConditioned in airConditionedList) {
            classroomList << c
        }
    }

    classroomList
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `filter` method to just be:

```
List filter(List<Integer> floorList, List<String> codeList, List<Boolean> airConditionedList) {
    classrooms.findAll { it.floor          in floorList }
              .findAll { it.code           in codeList }
              .findAll { it.airConditioned in airConditionedList }
}
```

So you could add the following to default empty lists to contain every possibility:

```
List filter(List<Integer> floorList, List<String> codeList, List<Boolean> airConditionedList) {
    // Make defaults for empty lists
    (floorList, codeList, airConditionedList) = [
        floor:floorList,
        code:codeList,
        airConditioned:airConditionedList
    ].collect { prop, list ->
        list ?: classrooms[prop].unique()
    }

    classrooms.findAll { it.floor          in floorList }
              .findAll { it.code           in codeList }
              .findAll { it.airConditioned in airConditionedList }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. After some testing i found a problem. If some of the input values are empty I get an empty list in response.

Comment: Yeah, because you're telling it to remove them by passing an empty list...  One sec, I'll try to come up with a defaults based solution